# Swift URL String Template Equivalent to Python

Tags: python, ios, swift, string, format

I'm making url requests to a web api. I'd like to make a template URL and then use string format to pass in the parameters. In Python this is very easy. Here's an example:
[image: Python Url Template Example]

I've been trying to do the equivalent in swift but it's made difficult since they use the percent sign with their format specifiers. I tried to research but came up on confusing constructs like percent encoding. Can I accomplish this in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried [string interpolation](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/5/string-interpolation)? That would look like `"http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(variable1)&page=\(variable2)"`.

Comment: I did but it required the extra step of setting the variables prior to using the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily in Swift without any special string "magic" by creating a function that takes in a `String` and an `Int` then returning a `String`.

```
// Create the template function
let urlTemplate: (String, Int) -> String = { (string, number) in
    return "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\(string)&page=\(number)"
}

// Then call it with whatever parameter (they will have to be a String and and Int though
urlTemplate("One", 1) // => "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=One&page=1"
urlTemplate("Banana", 82) // => "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Banana&page=82"
```

You can also use the shorthand closure syntax

```
let urlTemplate: (String, Int) -> String = { return "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\($0)&page=\($1)" }
```

Comment: OR `let urlTemplate: (String, Int) -> String = { return "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=\($0)&page=\($1)" }`  , if you wanna make use of shorthand arguments. ;)

Comment: Ahh I never thought to use closures. Thank you very much!